# Make Mobile site from Desktop site

Tags: php, eclipse, xcode, android-studio

I want to make a mobile site from a desktop site.how can I do that without access to server.I want show some part of that desktop site.not all part.
P.S: is not important that answer was android, ios, php tutorial.thanks

Comment: Is this for the purposes of showing a client what their site would look like on a mobile device?

Comment: Yes.client open url in mobile app.user select some button then show sepiticated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify a site without access to the server.

Assuming you want to show someone.
All you can do is to reproduce the same UI and use a webservice like [Invision](http://www.invisionapp.com/) to build the prototype of desktop and mobile site.

There are other free wireframe tools as mentioned [here](http://codecondo.com/free-wireframe-tools/)